# Swift UI forms - Why so much space?

Tags: forms, swiftui

why is there so much space in my form?

I want to have the first TextField at the top of the View
i hope someone can help me thank you guys.

[image]

Code:

```
var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            Form{
                Section(header: Text("Kunde")){
                    TextField("Vorname", text: $vorName)
                    TextField("Name", text: $name)
                }.frame(alignment: .top)
                Section(header: Text("Telefonnummer")) {
                    TextField("Mobil", text: $number)
                        .lineSpacing(10)
                        .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
                        .lineLimit(10)
                        .keyboardType(.numberPad)
                    TextField("Festnetz", text: $home)
                        .lineSpacing(10)
                        .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
                        .lineLimit(10)
                        .keyboardType(.numberPad)
                } 
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

From what I see on the screenshot - the application has `NavigationView` somewhere in the hierarchy. And then there is another `NavigationView` added as part of the current view.

**The first step** is to remove the nested `NavigationView` from the current screen. One `NavigationView` should be enough in this case. So, the code becomes:

```swift
var body: some View {
    Form {
        Section(header: Text("Kunde")){
        ....
    }
}
```

Then, there will be a bit of space added by the navigation bar as it has `automatic` style by default.
[image: Form with automatic navigation bar style]

So **the second step** is to remove this space. We can change the navigation bar style to `inline` like this:

```swift
var body: some View {
    Form {
        ... the form code ...
    }
    .navigationBarTitle("Title", displayMode: .inline) // the title can be empty string if needed
}
```

And it finally becomes a nicely laid out form:

[image: the result of the changes]